# Android Back End Technology - Language (Java, Python) & IDE (CoderBuddy, exo Cloud, Cloud 9)

Tags: java, android, python, ide, cloud

I've done my research and narrowed this down.  OK, so I am deciding on the language and and tool to use for backend (server side) of developing cloud based android applications..  I've decided on Google App Engine as my framework.  As I am going to be  developing on my android tablet I want a cloud based IDE.  (I am going to use a native android IDE app for client side).

App Engine supports the Go Programming Language, Java and Python.  As there doesn't appear to be a stable cloud IDE that supports Go, I am left with Java & Python.  I've narrowed my vast list of IDEs down to:

Coderbuddy - (Designed for App Engine but Python only)
exo Cloud - (Java & Python supported)
Cloud 9 - (Java & Python supported)

I know neither language.  I have to learn Java in any case for Android client side development.  I understand that Python is faster to code in and so that's definately a factor but I absolutely don't want to sacrifice performance or scalability.  I will be doing lots of SQL database stuff.

Finally if you think I am way off and should look in another direction please let me know.  Thanks!

Edit: My background language is Delphi (Object Pascal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that using Java you will have lots of frameworks to find solutions and I really don't think Python will offer you that.

About IDE, I don't think you should worry about it with Python, you can use SublimeText 2 or Eclipse(have to install python editor). Both work great and Python is easy to deploy.

With Java I use Eclipse but a friend is using NetBeans and it has some "shortcuts" to create things like services, for instance.

Also with Java, you'll be more familiarized because of Android so I think it is a plus, makes more sense.

You need to at least start so you can have a better idea of what is best for you.

And get ready, it will be a LOT different from Delphi ;)